# Markerclusterer - Triggering click event of a specific marker based on it's 'id' within a continuous marker array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, markerclusterer

Before implementing MarkerClusterer, I've been able to trigger the click event of specific markers (which then brings up a panel specific to that marker) by first loading up the marker array like this:

```
markers[marker.id] = marker;
```

(Where marker.id is a property set when drawing the marker from the JSON, that corresponds to a user record in my database)

Then calling:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(markers[id], 'click');
```

(Where 'id' is the user's id I want to click the marker for)

Now that I want to use MarkerClusterer however, it won't cluster using the array loading method I use above, I assume because there are then 'gaps' in my marker array as I don't draw markers for all users.

...MarkerClusterer works when I load my marker array like this:

```
markers.push(marker);
```

I assume this gives a continuous array without gaps that MarkerClusterer can read... but now I can't trigger the correct marker's click by it's index in the array.

So it seems I need a way of finding the .indexOf a marker in the continuous marker array based on marker.id...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least 2 options:

1. iterate through the "continuous" array of markers looking for the one that has the correct id (inefficient, requires additional processing with large numbers of markers), then trigger the click event on that.
2. create your associative array also, use it for triggering the click event (inefficient, requires memory for an additional array)

Comment: Thanks for this. I was thinking, how about if clicking on a user's name (in my user list next to the map) just pans the map to the user's lat/lng (loaded from the database), where there will of course be the marker... this might be enough on its own, but might it be possible then to trigger a click event at the center of the map view somehow? (hitting the marker thats there) ? Any hacky way to do this or anything?